# Параллельные запросы JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Всем привет, есть пример динамической подгрузки контента на страницу при нажатии на кнопку

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#imgLoad").hide();  //Скрываем прелоадер
});
var num = 5; //чтобы знать с какой записи вытаскивать данные
$(function() {
   $("#load div").click(function(){ //Выполняем если по кнопке кликнули
   $("#imgLoad").show(); //Показываем прелоадер
   $.ajax({
          url: "action.php",
          type: "GET",
          data: {"num": num},
          cache: false,
          success: function(response){
              if(response == 0){  // смотрим ответ от сервера и выполняем соответствующее действие
                 alert("Больше нет записей");
                 $("#imgLoad").hide();
              }else{
                 $("#content").append(response);
                 num = num + 5;
                 $("#imgLoad").hide();
              }
           }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Подскажите как сделать одновременно несколько параллельных запросов, но не больше 5, если больше 5 то нужно блокировать кнопку, пока висит 5 незавершенных запросов?

Если запрос отвалился, или если сервер вернул код ответа не 200 то выдать ошибку.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: капитан подсказывает, что надо завести счетчик кликов, увеличивать при клике, и уменьшать в `success/error`

Comment: Счетчик это понятно но будут ли эти запросы параллельными?

Comment: Я думал о том что может нужно делать очередь запросов? Подскажите как лучше сделать если можно с примером, спасибо!

Comment: аякс запрос и так асинхронный. код вашей функции выполнится быстрее, чем вы второй раз мышкой кликнуть успеете.

Comment: а что если сделать через jquery deferred?